# Python-How to get rid of brackets, quotations, and commas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python, and I'm doing a program for a tic tac toe game. In order to be able to manipulate the board later on, I've made it an array.

```
a=[["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"]]
def ttt(a):
for x in range (0,3):
        print (a[x])
z=ttt(a)
print(z)
```

However, when it prints, it prints:

```
['-', '-', '-']
['-', '-', '-']
['-', '-', '-']
```

How can I get rid of the brackets, quotations, and commas so it just prints:

```
- - -
- - -
- - -
```

Thanks!

Comment: Indent correctly; while it might not solve your problem, it's vital that you indent correctly for the sake of functionality of the program

Comment: `' 'join(a[x])` does that

Comment: You could also do `print(*a[x])`

Comment: `ttt()` does not return anything, so why do you assign `z` to it and print it?

Comment: There are many useful results in a Google search of this question's exact title.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make these small changes.  I'm sorry if I'm guessing wrong about your level of experience:

- You need to indent your code correctly.  Python uses indention, instead of the braces in other languages, to determine the end of the function and for loops.
- Decide where to print.   If calling `ttt` is going to print the game board, then it should not return any value.   If calling `ttt` is going to return a multiline string to print, it should not do any printing itself.   That is, decide if `ttt` means `print_ttt_board(board)` or
  `format_ttt_board(board)`.   Right now, you are printing the return value in the function, and not returning a value.  `z=ttt(a)` always sets z to `None` because there is no return value, and `print(z)` is doing nothing.
- Use individual values.   Right now, you are looping through the top level arrays (one array per row) and printing them.   That is, the first row is the array `["-", "-", "-"]`.   You want your loop to find the array that is the first row, and then loop or join over the second row.  You are currently
  printing an array, and Python gives you the handy debuggable output so you can see it an array.
- Use Python's `join()` method.  It's like "string-between-each-element-of-an-array".join(the_array).  Instead of `print(a[x])` where `a[x]` is an arry of three strings, you `print(" ".join(a[x])` meaning printing each item in `a[x]` separated by a space.

You need to start somewhere, and don't give up.   There will be other advice when you try this code later:  putting the `def` at the top, naming variables and functions so the meaning is clear, using for loops that iterate over the rows instead of the index to row, and so on.  This are all aimed at making your code run and making your intentions clear to 
anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can join your sublists with space which makes it a string and then print:

```
a=[["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"]]
def ttt(a):
    for x in range (0,3):
        print(" ".join(a[x]))
z=ttt(a)

- - -
- - -
- - -
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function

def print_board(a):
    for row in board:
        for char in row:
            print(' {}'.format(char), end='')
        print('')

board = [["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"]]
print_board(board)
```